# How do i get value of select options/index from looped array to my component so i can proses it in my component.ts

Tags: angular5

I have read through a number of Stack Overflow questions but none appear to be relevant to the problem I'm trying to solve.

i have a component.html which my select option get its value using *ngFor from my product quantity

```
<form class="form">
      <select [(ngModel)]="selectedQuantity" (ngModelChange)="setQtyValue()" name="quantitySelector">
        <option  *ngFor = "let totalQty of productQty; index as i"  [attr.data-index] ="i" [value]="totalQty[i]">{{totalQty}}</option>
      </select>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/cart']" (click)="addToCart()">
        Add to bag
      </button>
    </form>
```

And in my component.ts

```
selectedQuantity: Number

constructor( ) { }

setQtyValue(){
    this.selectedQuantity = +this.selectedQuantity  
    console.log(this.selectedQuantity)
  }

  addToCart(){

    console.log(selectedIndex)
    this.productDetails.map(product =>{
      console.log(this.productDetails)
      this.productSelected = {
        name : product.name,
        pictureUrl : product.pictures,
        qty : this.selectedQuantity,
        timestamp : new Date().getTime()
      }
    })
    this.cartService.addToCart(this.productSelected)
  }
```

I've tried many ways to get the value of selected index/option but it always log as undefined.
What do i need to change from code above to get and what do in my component.ts to get its value as number so i can then later on process it on my service.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to manually increment the 'selectedQuantity' when you use two-way data binding.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form class="form">
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedQuantity" name="quantitySelector">
            <option *ngFor="let totalQty of productQty" [value]="totalQty">{{totalQty}}</option>
        </select>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addToCart()">Add to bag</button>
    </form>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  productQty: number[] = Array.from({ length: 99 }, (v, k) => k + 1);
  selectedQuantity: Number = 1;

  addToCart() {
    console.log(this.selectedQuantity);

    //...
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13ebb2

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering your solution worked!! Though i still set the productQty array with push method.
It seems im having problem when i try to put _index as i_

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(selectedIndex)`? did you mean `this.selectedQuantity`? Also you **havent set an initial value for `selectedQuantity`** and so it is undefined

Comment: Hi thanks for answering my question...
the `console.log(selectedIndex)` was from earlier test when i already tried logging `this.selectedQuantity` to console  but the value is undefined. With  @Fouad Messaia and your answer im finally able to get the value i wanted